# iOS always add white background to images

Tags: ios, image-processing

I am writing an app process image. But when I change alpha of an image to 0, it mean that this image will be transparent. And then I save this image to photo library.

```
 UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum(image, nil, nil, nil);
```

But when I open this image again, i see that it has white background.
Does anybody know why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you saved as jpeg?

try this:

```
NSData* pngdata = UIImagePNGRepresentation (image); 
UIImage* img = [UIImage imageWithData:pngdata];
UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum(img, nil, nil, nil);
```